# How are the endpoints of motion determined?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

The Hamilton's principle tells us which path is taken by the system in going from one point of the configuration space at time t1 to another point of the configuration space at time t2. My question is how do we know what the endpoints are? I mean how does the system know its endpoint if it has to choose the path of least action?

Comment: This is a good question. Note that in practice however we derive from Hamilton's principle by Euler-Lagrange an equation of motion which can be solved as an initial value problem with input of position and velocity. You can think of this as the limit where the endpoints $x(0), x(dt)$ coincide except for an infinitesimal increment, $v dt$. So something amazing happens which is that Hamilton's principle also solves for the trajectory "beyond the endpoints", because the equations of motion are second order.

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03429